# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error in Android

Tags: android, jna, dalvik

I know this question has been asked a lot but I cannot seem to find the solution to the problem:

```
[2013-05-06 14:22:12 - MobileBim-android] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2013-05-06 14:22:12 - MobileBim-android] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
[2013-05-06 14:23:01 - MobileBim-android] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.sun.jna.Native$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2013-05-06 14:23:01 - MobileBim-android] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(com.sun.jna.Native$2) that doesn't come with an
...
[2013-05-06 14:23:02 - MobileBim-android] Dx 
trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
```

What should I do to solve this problem? add something to the manifest in dependencies?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I added the jna 3.3.0 source code files to my project, I still get the same error, so I guess something must be ignoring them and still going for some other jna library file.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: what version of java are you using? What are you trying to build? An app or a system?

Comment: I am using java 1.6 compiler in Eclipse.
I am trying to build an application created in Libgdx framework. Up till know I had no problems, but suddenly this error appears. It is an App.

Comment: Actually I cannot find any com.sun.jna imports in any of my own classes... I guess it must be something inside an imported package... But then again, I dont know much about it :)

Comment: JNA normally compiles for 1.4-level compatibility (1.5 for platform.jar).  It is easily rebuilt with a different ant property setting representing the compatibility level (`ant -Dcompatibility=1.6`).

Comment: Tried to compile the sources within my project, didnt work :(

Comment: You'd need to find the version of JNA being referenced by your other project dependencies and ensure that the version with older class format is ignored or removed.